# ajax online examination system for frontend in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to make online examination system. I have three tables. Table "student" has details of students, column id identifies students uniquely. Table "tests" has details of all the tests available and there is a column id which contains id of tests. and then I have tables of tests which contains questions and answers.

now i want to ask that how to call question in frontend using ajax. How can I achieve that? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little strange how you have phrased this question from a database point of view. I'll assume you know that you need to setup Laravel routes and models and that all you are struggle with is the frontend AJAX.

Easiest way to do this is to download [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and use the AJAX function in your javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
```

});